# WCF - Getting CommunicationException

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I have a WCF service that is providing Authentication/Authorization for a different WCF service.

Here is a sample method:

```
 public int AddCustomerStopInfo(CustomerStop stop)
            {
                var request = new AddCustomerStopInfoRequest(stop);

                var service = new ChannelFactory<IAccountManagementChannel>("WSHttpBinding_IAccountManagement").CreateChannel();

                try
                {
                    var response = service.AddCustomerStopInfo(request);
                    service.Close();

                    return response.AddCustomerStopInfoResult;
                }
                catch (CommunicationException e)
                {
                    service.Abort();
                    throw;
                }

            }
```

On the service.AddCustomerStopInfo() method call, an exception is thrown. The message reads:

> Secure channel cannot be opened because security negotiation with the
>   remote endpoint has failed. This may be due to absent or incorrectly
>   specified EndpointIdentity in the EndpointAddress used to create the
>   channel. Please verify the EndpointIdentity specified or implied by
>   the EndpointAddress correctly identifies the remote endpoint.

The server binding for the service looks like:

```
 <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IAccountManagement" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="100065536"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
          allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
            enabled="false" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>

...

 <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ABCD.Service.Service1Behavior"
        name="ABCD.Service.AccountManagement">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="ValidationBehavior"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IAccountManagement"
          name="WSHttpBinding_IAccountManagement" contract="ABCD.Service.IAccountManagement">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" behaviorConfiguration="" binding="mexHttpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
```

And the client side:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="[site location]/AccountManagement.svc"
    binding="wsHttpBinding" 
    contract="IAccountManagement" name="WSHttpBinding_IAccountManagement">
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

Both services are on the same server. I don't understand why I am getting this error if the other service has `<security mode="None">` ?

Comment: Do you have a security certificate for the server? Is it self signed? Are you specifying a `https` address? Have you got the username and password correct?

Comment: Yes there is a cert, and yes its self signed. (This is in a test environment.) I am not specifying https. Let me try these and get back to you - I didnt think this was an issue.

Comment: You've got a `wsHttpBinding` so you should be using `https`, though it's not mandatory. If you're in a test environment you'll probably have to add code to allow a permissive connection to the test server.

Comment: Setting up Https and adding permissive connection solved the problem. If you write it up as an answer, I will mark it for you. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are trying to use a secure binding via `wsHttpBinding` you will need to connect to the server via https and use debug code to allow a permissive connection to your test server.

This is because you'll only have a self signed certificate and https is really strict when it comes to security certificates.